# Vectorizing with variable array indices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm running python with numpy, and I have a loop which, stripped down, looks like this:

```
result = np.zeros(bins)
for i in xrange(bins):
    result[f(i)] += source[i]
```

Here, both result and source are numpy arrays, and f is a mildly complicated set of arithmetic operations. For example, one simplified example of f might look like

```
f = lambda x: min(int(width*pow(x, 3)), bins-1)
```

though f is generally not monotonic in its argument.

This loop is currently the bottleneck in my program. I managed to vectorize everything else, but I'm currently stumped on how to do it here. How can this loop be vectorized?

Comment: To (possibly) vectorize this calculation we need to see the definition of `f`.

Comment: @unutbu f is pretty complicated and varies, but it always contains only the Python math functions/operators: pow, min, max, floor, <, >, log. Would it help if I gave an explicit example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To vectorize `f`
the main idea is to replace scalar operations with numpy vector-based functions.
For example, if originally we have

```
def f(x):
    return min(int(width*pow(x, 3)), bins-1)
```

then we could instead use

```
def fvec(x):
    return np.minimum((width*np.power(x, 3)).astype(int), bins-1)
```

There is a natural correspondence between some Python scalar functions and NumPy
vectorized functions:

```
| pow   | np.power   |
| min   | np.minimum |
| max   | np.maximum |
| floor | np.floor   |
| log   | np.log     |
| <     | np.less    |
| >     | np.greater |
```

The vectorized functions take an array of inputs and returns an array of the same shape.
However, there are other constructs which may not be so obvious. For example the
vectorized equivalent of `x if condition else y` is `np.where(condition, x, y)`.

Unfortunately, in general there is no simple shortcut. Translating from
scalar function to vectorized function may require any one of the many
NumPy functions available, as well NumPy concepts like broadcasting and advanced
indexing.

---

For example, it is tempting at this point to replace

```
for i in range(bins):
    result[f(i)] += source[i]
```

with the [integer-array indexed assignment](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays):

```
result[fvec(np.arange(bins))] += source
```

but this produces an incorrect result if `fvec(np.arange(bins))` has repeated values. Instead use
[`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) since this correctly accumulates multiple `source` values when `fvec(np.arange(bins))` indicates the same bin:

```
result = np.bincount(fvec(np.arange(bins)), weights=source, minlength=bins)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bins = 1000
width = 1.5
source = np.random.random(bins)

def fvec(x):
    return np.minimum((width*np.power(x, 3)).astype(int), bins-1)

def f(x):
    return min(int(width*pow(x, 3)), bins-1)

def orig():
    result = np.zeros(bins)
    for i in range(bins):
        result[f(i)] += source[i]
    return result

def alt():
    result = np.bincount(fvec(np.arange(bins)), weights=source, minlength=bins)
    return result

assert np.allclose(orig(), alt())
```

---

For the example above with `bins=1000`, `alt` is about 62x faster than `orig` (on my machine):

```
In [194]: %timeit orig()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 ms per loop

In [195]: %timeit alt()
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.8 µs per loop
```

The speed advantage of `alt` over `orig` will increase as the number of iterations required by `orig`'s `for-loop` increases -- that is, as `bins` increases.

Comment: i just implemented this and got a speedup of 100x. great stuff!